# Calculate $E(Y)$ and $Var(Y)$ given the random variable which is exponentially distributed

Tags: probability

The random variable $X$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda = \dfrac{1}{2}$.
Also, define $Y = -2X + 1$. Calculate $E(Y)$ and $Var(Y)$.

So we have

$$f_X(x) = \dfrac{1}{2} e^{-\dfrac{1}{2}x} $$  if $x\ge0$ and $0$ otherwise.

But how to calculate $E(Y)$ and $Var(Y)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the formulas $$E[aX+b]=aE[X]+b\quad \text{ and } \quad Var(aX+b)=(a)^2Var(X)+0$$ you have that $$E[Y]=E[-2X+1]=-2E[X]+1$$ and $$Var(Y)=Var(-2X+1)=(-2)^2Var(X)+0=4Var(X)$$ Now use (or calculate) that since $X$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $λ=\frac{1}{2}$ then  $$E[X]=\frac{1}{λ}=2\quad \text{ and } \quad Var(X)=\frac{1}{λ^2}=4$$